# How to keep the Microphone volume up, and disallow apps to change it

Tags: macos, audio, microphone

I have this issue on my Mac:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/microsoft-teams-keeps-adjusting-my-microphone/58475db0-2d0b-43e6-a012-29efe938f983

No one have a good solution that I find. When I mute my Jabra, Micorosft team adjust the volume to low, when I unmute it's still low and no one can hear me.

To fix that, I want to to disallow Teams to adjust the volume, or to keep app in the background that adjust it to high every 1 second.

Comment: This also happen with sound output and it's plain stupid:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8010316

Sometimes I am going to enter a Teams call but I am listening to music until everyone joins the call. However, when I join the Teams app will simply increase my system volume and the music will get too high, so I have to manually decrease the volume.